# Using one-page URL alongside search function

Tags: php, mysql, loops, search

First of all, apologies if this question seems repetitive or one that you feel I have not done my due diligence on. I normally scour the Internet before, but I feel as if I need to ask.

So, basically, I'm building a one-page dynamic website which lists some attractions in my local city. That part I'm alright with - I created a database using MySQL, I have 1 database, 4 different tables each of which have different ID names.

My problem is, my Search is only limited to what the user enters i.e. the name of the attraction and I'm struggling to actually link it to any of the dynamic URL (Except the first table the loop queries)

My code below explains why it does this, and I hope to God someone out there can lead me to the answer, whether that be an external link etc. I'll be most grateful and forever indebted.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
?>



<?php



            mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "everydayleeds") or die(mysqli_error());
            mysqli_select_db($con, "everydayleeds") or die(mysqli_error());  /* everydayleeds is the name of database we've created */


            $query = $_GET['query']; // 'query' is the variable name given to the $_GET action, which will take whatever is typed into the search box, indicating this via the URL paramater'

            $min_length = 3; // You can set minimum length of the query if you want


            if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ // If query length is more or equal minimum length then

                $query = htmlspecialchars($query); // This changes characters used in HTML to their equivalents, for example: < to &gt;

                $query = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $query); // Makes sure nobody uses SQL injection


                $raw_results = mysqli_query ($con, "SELECT foodndrink.Name AS fdName, nightlife.Name AS nightName, culture.Name AS cultName, placestostay.Name AS pName, foodndrink.fdID AS foodID, nightlife.nightID AS nID, cultID AS cID, placesID AS pID FROM foodndrink, nightlife, culture, placestostay


                    WHERE (foodndrink.Name LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (nightlife.Name LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (culture.Name LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (placestostay.Name LIKE '%".$query."%') ") OR die (mysqli_error($con));


                if(mysqli_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // If one or more rows are returned do following

                    while($results = mysqli_fetch_assoc($raw_results)){  // $results = mysql_fetch_assoc($raw_results) puts data from database into array, while it's valid it does the loop            
                         echo "Yes, we have a".$_GET['query']."<a href=attractions.php?category&fdID=".$results['foodID'];

break;

                    }

                }

                else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
                    echo "<p>Nope, Leeds probably doesn't have a </p>".$_GET['query'];
                }

            }
            else{ // if query length is less than minimum
                echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
            }




?>
```

So, the link in which the user can click on once they have found a result is ONLY linking back to the Food N Drinks page due to the fact that I have the `?category&fdID=".$results['foodID'];` set in place.

I've tried looping, JOINs, and I seem to be going around in circles. I believe my issue is just the fact that I have 4 different tables with all 4 different IDs.

Any advice, help would be most appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, are you not able to see the code? The code preview didn't seem to catch all my code, but I used the HTML preview one instead..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think that if you use "Union all" method, you can add static texts to results of each table. There is a sample [in here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/76190).

After that, you can make something like that

```
echo "<a href=attractions.php?category&".$results['tableName']."&ID=".$results['foodID'];
```

Comment: Yeah, I came across UNION today, I think my answer may lie within that. I'll have a look, thank you!